# Unable to connect to AWS RDS using Liquibase on Mac

Tags: sql, macos, liquibase

I am unable to connect to an AWS RDS instance using liquibase from the terminal using a Mac. I am able to connect to the same database and URL using MySQL workbench and pymysql in python. I have `mysql-connector-java.jar` in Liquibase's lib folder. I have also done `brew install mysql` and `brew install mysql-client`. I get the same error when using an invalid URL, but I have checked (many times) to make sure the URL string is correct. The exact error I get is:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mysql://-URL IS HERE-?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true with driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.  Communications link failure

From the command:

```
liquibase --url=jdbc:mysql://-URL IS HERE-:3306/cdp_sms?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true  --username="cdpadmin" --password=$CDP_DB_PW --changeLogFile=db.changelog-master.xml update
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had encounter a similar issue a while ago with Liquibase and AWS RDS. I would suggest you to check your security groups (inbound/outbound rules) in the aws settings.